# Why $\text{Var}\left[ X e^{\lambda X}\right]\le \frac{(b-a)^2}{4}$?

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a bounded random variable between $[a,b]$. It can be shown that
$$\text{Var}\left[ X\right] \le \frac{(b-a)^2}{4}$$

Let $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. Why is it true that

$$\text{Var}\left[ X e^{\lambda X}\right]\le \frac{(b-a)^2}{4}\, ?$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This inequality is incorrect.  For $X \sim \text{Bernoulli}(1/2)$, we have $a = 0$, $b=1$, but
$$
\text{Var}(Xe^{\lambda X}) = E[X^2 e^{2\lambda X}] - E[Xe^{\lambda X}]^2 = \frac{1}{2} e^{2\lambda} - \frac{1}{4}e^{2\lambda} = \frac{1}{4}e^{2\lambda}
$$
This is unbounded in $\lambda$, so taking $\lambda = 10$ for instance breaks the inequality.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are actually working with the exponentially tilted random variable $\tilde{X}$ which has distribution $P(\tilde{X} \in A) = \frac{E[e^{\lambda X} \mathbf{1}_{X \in A}]}{E[e^{\lambda X}]}$.
Since $\tilde{X}$ also takes values in $[a,b]$, it immediately satisfies $\text{Var}[\tilde{X}] \le (b-a)^2/4$. Note $\tilde{X}$ is not the same as $X e^{\lambda X}$.

Comment: That is what I'm looking at! But it's not clear to me why $\tilde{X}$ is in $[a,b]$ as well. I am given that $X$ has density $p$, and $\tilde{X}$ has density $Z\cdot e^{\lambda x} p(x)$ where $Z$ is normalizing constant...

Comment: @YukiKawabata One way to understand is to ask yourself where the new density is nonzero.

Comment: Oh... Because $p\left(x\right) = 0$ almost everywhere outside $[a,b]$, so $e^{\lambda x} p\left(x\right) = 0$ almost everywhere outside $[a,b]$?